# Do browsers ever unload loaded scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, v8

I was investigating if loading one script perpetually would increase the memory usage of a browser tab. This seems like a memory leak to me from Chrome, unless this is the way it works.
The script is just loading this crypto library forever and each request is sequential, once it loads one it removes it and load another.

```js
let count = 0;
function load(cb) {
   var url = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/aes.js?bust=${count}`;
  count++;
 let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.id = count + 'script';
  script.onload = cb;
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function doit() {
  load(() => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      let script = document.getElementById( count + 'script');
      document.body.removeChild(script);
      doit();
    }, 100);
  });
}

doit();
```

after loading the script 10,000 times it went from 40mb to 400mb ish, to measure this I'm using the Chrome Task Manager

https://jsbin.com/votejebobu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: The garbage collector should clean things up.  As long as your loaded script has no reference to any globals.

Comment: you can try any script , in this case every load should override whatever global reference is using. It doesn't accumulate.

Comment: No, be careful.  If your scripts used things like `setInterval / setTimeout & addEventListeners` or even adding functions to a global object or array,  it would keep those instances of the script in memory.  So in these case it would indeed accumulate.

Comment: This library, in particular, is not using addEventListener or timers.. but there's a perpetual timer in the jsbin script.